# How can I call click event when drag and drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change event drag and drop, to click event for my objects.
I try this code

```
 $("a").draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).trigger("click");
    }
});
```

But not work :(

**UPDATE:**

I try this code:

```
document.ondragstart = function () {
return false;
};

document.onmouseup = function (a, b) {
$(this).trigger("click");
};
```

But trigger click still not work

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: No errors return. trigger("click"); not working.

Comment: Are you trying to make it clickable when the dragging is still happening ?

Comment: can you try replicating the scenario on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this modification:

```
$("a").draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(--your-button-element-here-).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Greg try change `this` to the id of your button (see update)

Answer (score 0):

I found just such a solution

```
var url = null;
        $("a").mousedown(function () {
            url = $(this).attr("href");
            $(window).mousemove(function () {
                $(window).unbind("mousemove");
            });
        });
        $(window).mouseup(function () {
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");
            if (url != null) {
                location.href = url;
            }
        });
```